# Can I link to workbooks that haven't been created yet if I know what they will be named?

Tags: vba, excel

We use an excel sheet (called an "Assign") to store info for a particular day. A new Assign is created each day and placed in the same folder, the previous day's is removed. I know what the name of the new Assigns will be before they're created, it goes by date ('May 19 Assign', 'May 20 Assign', etc...)

I have a sheet that I want to link to the daily Assign. It's a straight forward VLOOKUP that I need to do to get data from the daily Assign workbook, but since it's a new file each day, I'm just wondering if there's a way to have the links update automatically to the new file?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to use a fixed name for the file (and maybe rename them with the date as they're removed?)

Comment: You could use Find & Replace functionality to update the formula references. I think you could create formulas referencing non-existent workbooks but that will display an error (I think `#REF!`) until the workbook exists.

Answer (score 0):

For the easiest solution, see Tim's comment.

You COULD write a UDF that returns the latest fileName.  This one below would return "C:\MyPath\myFile_20140519.xls" for today.

```
Function GetLatestFileName() As String
    GetLatestFileName = "C:\MyPath\myFile_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls"
End Function
```

Then you could enter it in a cell etc and it would change dynamically.